# Don't understand error message (required: variable, found: value)

Tags: java, class, variables, object, arraylist

The error message pertains to this line of code

```
Player a = pl.get(i);
/*
* CODE MODIFTYING VARIABLES WITHIN THE OBJECT a
*/
pl.get(i) = a;
```

'pl' is an ArrayList of the class Player

this code is in a for loop where 'i' is equal to the number of intervals the for loop has gone through

it specifies that "(i)" is a variable an it should be a value, what does it mean by value???

Basically, I'm copying my Player object in my array list and setting it to a Player object variable that is created within the for loop and changing the values within the object and then setting the newly created object (Player a)  to my index in the ArrayList (pl.get(i))

I'm doing this so I don't have to keep writing pl.get(i).getFunction() pl.get(i).setFunction() pl.get(i).CalculateFunction() pl.get(i).blablabla();

I can just use a.whatever = 83465;

So the question is, what am I missing?

Comment: `pl.get(i) = a;` will not update your list element.

Answer (score 0):

pl.get(i) is a value type (rvalue) and can not be assigned a new value.
Only lvalues can be assigned values.
You have to use the set method of ArrayList to overwrite values in the list:
`pl.set(i, a);`

Additionally, when calling pl.get(i) to retrieve the element you named a, you can use this reference to change `a` in any way you want. you don't have to write the object back into the list, as the reference is still there.